# R - Fitting X-Axis Labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently making a bar plot using ggplot2, however, the x-axis labels are very squished together and I cannot read them.  I have read other examples of people tilting these at a 45 degree angle, which is definitely one option.  I tried this to no avail with the code below:

```
ggplot(data = Overall_survival, 
       aes(x=reorder(Name, -OS), y=OS, fill = factor(Best_Response))) + 
  ylim(0, 50) + 
  ylab("Overall Survival (months)") + 
  xlab("Response by Name") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  ggtitle("Overall Survival in Patients Treated with Treatment (n=35)") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Best Response"))
```

Should I tilt the labels so that the "Name" fits beneath each bar, or is there a way to decrease the font size so that it fits horizontal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your code example reproducible to facilitate troubleshooting https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's impossible to know exactly what's going on and what this looks like without seeing your data. Please `dput` a workable sample of your data

Answer (score 1):

You can play around yourself, but you access the elements of each plot via `theme`:

```
ggplot(...) +
... +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

You can substitute `text` for `axis.text.x` or `axis.text.y`, etc..